# Check if a property value has changed on POCO

Tags: c#

I have a POCO that is updated every N seconds. The problem I have is that not all properties may have changed since the last update.

I need to know which properties have changed since the last update so I can log the changes. I could do this by keeping a copy of the POCO from the previous update and performing a comparison each time and then maybe firing an event for each property change.

Does anyone have a better solution that I could use here?

Comment: What are you using to update the object (ADO, EF, NHibernate)?

Comment: Can you not simply log the full details of the POCO on each change?

Comment: @Oded - Yes I could but I'm going to be logging a lot of data and the duplicates will contribute a considerable increase in storage space which is avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx this is the standard way that plays nice with databinding.
- saving the state of each property as an "old" value every time you do your update is necessary in the situation where you only want to detect properties which have actually different values than last time - for example, if you don't want a property that changed from 5 to 3 to 7 back to 5 since last update.
- if you don't care about this distinction, and don't want to use propertychanged, you can give each property a bool value they you set to true in the setter, and set them to false every time you update.
- you can create a GetProperty/SetProperty mechanic - you call these functions in the setters/getters, and you can then save the actual data and any metadata about it in any way you want under the hood. However this is not really POCO any more.

Answer (score 2):

If it's truely a POCO then, no, you'll need to keep a copy. If you are willing to add an IsDirty flag to your POCO, you could set it when a property is changed. You could make the IsDirty flag a bitfield so that you know which properties were changed:

```
class POCO
{
[Flags]
enum POCOFieldsEnum
{
  Property1 = 0x01;
  Property2 = 0x02;
}

private String _Property1;
public String Property1 
{ 
  get { return _Property1; }
  set 
  { 
    if (value.Equals(_Property1)) return;
    _Property1 = value;
    DirtyFlags |= POCOFieldsEnum.Property1;
  }
}

private String _Property2;
public String Property2
{
  get { return _Property2; }
  set 
  { 
    if (value.Equals(_Property2)) return;
    _Property2 = value;
    DirtyFlags |= POCOFieldsEnum.Property2;
  }
}

POCOFieldsEnum DirtyFlags { private set; public get; }
}
```

Note that if such an object has a property changed and then changed back to its original value, the DirtyFlag would still be set. If you want to prevent this situation, you'd have to save the original value of properties (or a hash of them) with which to compare in the property setters.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hash of various properties and save it as a property itself, then compare again whilst verifying.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is nothing "built-in" to .NET to track any property change on a class. However any of the following should work:

1) Write code manually in the setter of each property to track a change.

2) Write some code that compares an 'old' copy to an 'updated' instance (the same thing you said in your original post).

3) Use an AOP framework (like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net)) to add some kind of update notification to each property.